# What is the best method to sqlalchemy object back to db table without pandas?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, mariadb

Please help me to solve the following task: I would need to update the DB table directly with the selected objects. Is there a call to do it?
I follow this way:

```py
summary = sql.Table('ABC', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
query = sql.select([summary]) 

ResultProxy = conn.execute(query)
ResultSet = ResultProxy.fetchall()
```

I can create a pandas DataFrame and use `.to_sql`, however I can't find the way to do it directly without pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've called `.fetchall` and received a list of `Row` objects you can convert that to a list of `dict` objects using the `_asdict` method, then pass that to an `insert` query:

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
    # Step 0.0: Create target table for this example
    conn.execute(sa.text("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp"))
    conn.execute(
        sa.text("CREATE TABLE tmp (id INT PRIMARY KEY, txt VARCHAR(50))")
    )
    tmp_table = sa.Table("tmp", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

    # Step 0.1: Create sample data for this example
    sql = """\
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'foo' AS txt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 'bar' AS txt
    """
    data_as_list_of_rows = conn.execute(sa.text(sql)).fetchall()
    print(data_as_list_of_rows)  # [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')]

    # Step 1: Convert to list of dict
    data_as_list_of_dict = [row._asdict() for row in data_as_list_of_rows]
    print(
        data_as_list_of_dict
    )  # [{'id': 1, 'txt': 'foo'}, {'id': 2, 'txt': 'bar'}]

    # Step 2: Perform the insert
    conn.execute(tmp_table.insert(), data_as_list_of_dict)

    # Step 3: Confirm the results
    result = conn.execute(tmp_table.select()).fetchall()
    print(result)  # [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')]
```

Comment: Hello Gord, many thanks. I've also found a solution in the meanwhile.
summary = sql.Table('ABC', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
query = sql.insert(summary) 
ResultProxy = conn.execute(query,ResultSet)